# Build error in Go/Golang: Column does not implement gorm.ColumnType (missing AutoIncrement method)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, build, go-gorm, govendor

I am facing this build error in Golang V1.17 intermittently.

```
# gorm.io/driver/mysql
../../../../pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/mysql@v1.2.1/migrator.go:224:24: cannot use column (type Column) as type gorm.ColumnType in append:
        Column does not implement gorm.ColumnType (missing AutoIncrement method)
```

I have tried restarting, clearing cache on VS Code, deleting go.mod and go.sum, and what-not.

Is there a workaround or something?

Comment: sharing more info on things like how you have defined your structs and the imports might help you get faster and better solutions. Also, did you do `go mod tidy` as well?

Answer (score 9):

my problem solved by installing mysql driver for gorm:

```sh
~  go get gorm.io/driver/mysql
```

Answer (score 5):

I solve it by update all relative package，it works：

```
go get gorm.io/gorm
go get gorm.io/driver/mysql
go get gorm.io/driver/sqlserver
go get gorm.io/driver/postgres

go mod vendor
```

Answer (score 3):

This is followed by [`go-gorm/gorm` issue 5096](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5096) which includes:

> I update the latest gorm module with the following command:
>
> ```sh
> rm -rf go.mod go.sum
> go mod init "panel"  # <== replace by your own project name
> go mod tidy
> go mod vendor
> ```
>
> After running the error, the replacement version is fine.
>
> ```sh
> go mod edit -require=gorm.io/driver/mysql@v1.2.3
> go mod edit -require=gorm.io/gorm@v1.22.5
> go mod vendor
> ```